# Given an array of objects, how do you create a new array of objects with different key names while also omitting unwanted data (ES6 way)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Sorry for the title, It's limited to 150 characters.

**Full code example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/c81zw30m/

**Data:**

Let's say I make an API request and I get this JSON object returned:

```
[
    {
        id: 123,
        person: {
            data: {
                name: 'John',
                language: 'Javascript'
            }
        },
        details: {
            age: 25
        },
        has_experience: true
    },
    {
        id: 456,
        person: {
            data: {
                name: 'Peter',
                language: null // here we have null as a value.
            }
        },
        details: {
            age: 40
        },
        has_experience: false
    },
    {
        id: 789,
        person: {
            data: {
                name: 'Paul',
                language: 'Python'
            }
        },
        details: {
            age: 30
        },
        has_experience: null // and here we also don't know if the person is available
    },
];
```

**Goal:**

The end goal here is to iterate over the array and end up with new array of objects with different key names. Say for example I want to replace the key of `person` with `human` or the key of `available` with `availability`.

Additionally (optionally) we want to skip adding keys which value is equal to `null`.

**Current solution:**

```
let results = [];

for (let i=0; i< json.length; i++) {

    results.push({
        user_id: json[i].id,
        name: json[i].person.data.name,
        age: json[i].details.age,
        has_experience: json[i].available ? json[i].available : false // here we are assigning a value no matter what using a ternary operator, what if we want no key:value pair here, just skip that pair
    });

    if (json[i].person.data.language) { results[i].language = json[i].person.data.language }
}

console.log(results);
```

**Problem:**

Now the example and solution I provided works, but imagine if the original API request had hundreds of key:value pairs, and many of them might be of `null` value.

**Question:**

Using modern javascript, is there any less verbose and more clean looking/elegant way to handle this problem?

Overall I am looking to create a brand new array of objects based on the original one, but with new key names where necessary. Additionally, we want to skip adding some of them if the value of the key is `null` for example.

Cheers.

---

**EDIT:**

Changed the key name from the example originally provided from `available` to `has_experience` because it was a bit misleading. I am not looking to filter out the original array of objects based on the value of a given key. If I wanted to do that I'd start with `filter` and then chain on.

What I want to do is to omit adding a key:value pair in the newly formed array if the value of the key is `null` for example.

Comment: Is the resulting object always supposed to be "flattened" into a single-level object (instead of using nested objects) ?

Comment: No, I want to be able to still have some nested inside of the final object.

Comment: that becomes a completely different problem then, especially if you want some of the fields to be flattened, and others not.

Comment: I've updated my answer so that it first maps every object into a completely flat one (albeit making the assumption that your leaf-node key names are unique) and then mapping some of those keys to new key names which may be arbitrarily nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `lodash` (or similar), you could get your mapping definition out of the mapping loop.
I find the following reasonably concise, though it can probably be shortened a little further.

```
import { get, set } from "lodash";

let json = [ ... ];

let mapping = new Map([
  ["user_id", "id"],
  ["name", "person.data.name"],
  ["age", "details.age"],
  ["availability", "available"],
  ["language", "person.data.language"],
  ["some.nested.property", "person.data.language"]
]);

var results = json.map(element => {
  var mappedElement = {};
  mapping.forEach((path, field, map) => {
    var value = get(element, path);
    if (value) {
      set(mappedElement, field, value);
    }
  });
  return mappedElement;
});

console.log(results);
```

Running this on your data yields

```
[Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
  user_id: 123
  name: "John"
  age: 25
  availability: true
  language: "Javascript"
  some: Object
    nested: Object
      property: "Javascript"
1: Object
  user_id: 456
  name: "Peter"
  age: 40
2: Object
  user_id: 789
  name: "Paul"
  age: 30
  language: "Python"
  some: Object
    nested: Object
      property: "Python"
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/mnkp79668

Comment: The OP apparently wants _some_ amount of nesting in the output.  `_.set` may help there, although I think it's undesirable to have to specify every possible key in the `mapping` table.

Comment: @wwerner this is near perfect, but is it possible to nest stuff when you are declaring a `new Map`. For example `["information.name, information.gender", "person.data.name, person.data.geneder"],` (this is pseudo code obviously). Additionally, I wonder what the `get` function of lodash is doing in the background and if that is achievable in plain javascript.

Comment: @decho `lodash` also provides a `set()` function corresponding to `get()`. I updated the example accordingly. And here's what `_.set` does: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/get.js

Comment: Thanks a ton @wwerner, this looks like a really clean solution and can potentially save me a ton of writing. I'm not familiar with lodash so I have to read their docs to make complete sense of your example but this is a great start so again thanks a lot. Hopefully I will be able to update the solution to of the original question after that.

Comment: @decho You should accept the answer if you feel it answers you question. Thank you comments are discouraged: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: There's a big bug in this - you need to check explicitly for `null` (returned perhaps as the default from `_.get()` because otherwise you'll ignore any other "falsey" values).    Also, be aware that this will _only_ copy those properties that are specifically enumerated in the mapping table.   That could get tedious (and error prone) if there are hundreds of them.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try something like this**

You can achieve with `map()`

```js
let json = [{id: 123, person: { data: { name: 'John', language: 'Javascript' } }, details: { age: 25 }, has_experience: true },
            {id: 456, person: { data: { name: 'Peter',language: null } }, details: { age: 40 }, has_experience: false},
            {id: 789, person: { data: { name: 'Paul', language: 'Python' } }, details: { age: 30 }, has_experience: null },];

let results = [];

results = json.map(current => {
    let temp = {
        user_id: current.id,
        name: current.person.data.name,
        age: current.details.age,
        
    }
    if (current.has_experience) {
        temp.availablity = current.has_experience
    }  
        if (current.person.data.language) 
        { temp.language = current.person.data.language }
    return temp;
})

console.log(results);
```

Comment: nowhere AFAICS did the OP specify that only `available` entries were to be included - they said that they want the `available` key to be _omitted_ if its value is `null`.

Comment: ***Overall I am looking to create a brand new array of objects based on the original one, but with new key names where necessary. Additionally, we want to skip adding some of them if the value of the key is null for example.***  this is what he has at end of question.

Comment: My reading is that he wants to skip those specific keys, not the entire object.

Comment: Can you please check my edit. I am trying to skip adding a key:value pair, not the whole array itself.

Comment: Alnitak, yes exactly.

Comment: @decho it was bit misleading. I updated my code.you can check.

Comment: @CodeManiac I am pretty sure that will work, appreciate the time you spend to help me. Just one question which was originally asked in the original post - is there any way to escape the countless `if` statements?

Comment: there's really no need to use `.reduce` here - this is a canonical use case for `.map`.

Comment: @decho the only way to reduce the amount of code to map from one set of nested keys to another is to write a data structure that contains that mapping, and then write generic code to do that mapping based on that data structure.

Comment: @Alnitak yeah now it became. before update reduce was needed

Answer (score 1):

You have two separate problems to resolve.   The first appears to be a requirement for generic *flattening* of the nested data structures within the input with out specifying every possible key that might exist.

This function will recursively flatten a nested object, along the way omitting any `null` values.   However, this function might overwrite any values where the same key exists at multiple levels, so see below.

```
function flatten(obj, dest) {
    for (let key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            flatten(obj[key], dest);
        } else if (obj[key] !== null) {
            dest[key] = obj[key];
        }
    } 
    return dest;
}
```

You also want to re-map some of the keys in your data, where the below function can be used both as a pre-processor to convert known duplicate keys into unique keys, and can also be used as a post-processor to convert particular keys back into nested objects.   NB: requires "lodash".

```
function remap(obj, keys) {
    for (let [in_key, out_key] of keys) {
        let val = _.get(obj, in_key, null);
        if (val !== null) {
                _.unset(obj, in_key);
                _.set(obj, out_key, val);
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

The functions can be chained together like this:

```
let in_map = new Map([
    ['user.id', 'user_id']
]);

let out_map = new Map([
    ['available', 'test.availability']
]);

let out = data.map(obj => remap(obj, in_map))
              .map(obj => flatten(obj, {}))
              .map(obj => remap(obj, out_map));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate the reply. I haven't tested this, and I assume it works, but it will not work for me because as you mentioned - it assumes that the key names are unique. In my case it's quite the opposite, keys like `book.id`, or `person.id` are actually rather common with the API i work with so if we flatten the object it will probably not work.

Comment: @decho it should be possible to take a similar approach that does a first pass remapping (nested) keys into new unique keys.   What I was trying to avoid was having to put _every single_ potential key into the data mapping structure.

Comment: @decho I've updated my answer accordingly - there's now a three pass system.   The first pass rewrites duplicate keys into unique keys.   The second pass completely flattens the structure.   The third pass then recreates any nested structures that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to first [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the list, then [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the filtered results to create the new structure.  This may not be especially performant however if the list is quite large.

```js
const list = [
    {
        id: 123,
        person: {
            data: {
                name: 'John',
                language: 'Javascript'
            }
        },
        details: {
            age: 25
        },
        available: true
    },
    {
        id: 456,
        person: {
            data: {
                name: 'Peter',
                language: null // here we have null as a value.
            }
        },
        details: {
            age: 40
        },
        available: false
    },
    {
        id: 789,
        person: {
            data: {
                name: 'Paul',
                language: 'Python'
            }
        },
        details: {
            age: 30
        },
        available: null // and here we also don't know if the person is available
    },
];

const newList = list.filter(listItem => listItem.available).map(filteredItem => {
  return {
        user_id: filteredItem.id,
        name: filteredItem.person.data.name,
        age: filteredItem.details.age,
        availability: !!filteredItem.available
    }
})

document.getElementById('list').innerText = JSON.stringify(list, null, 2);
document.getElementById('newList').innerText = JSON.stringify(newList, null, 2);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container pre {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<pre id="list"></pre>
<pre id="newList"></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: You are providing a perfect solution, but I also provided a bad example. I am not looking to filter out results that have `available` as false from my results, otherwise I'd chain `filter` and `map` just like you did. I am simply trying to exclude certain key:value pairs from the final array of results if the value corresponds to null if that makes sense.